# Ubuntu doesn't download files using apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, ppa

When I type the command `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu 14.04, it downloads most of  the files but the other ones say for example:

> Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Now, whenever I install a PPA key, it installs but when I run `sudo apt-get update` it fails to download the files. This applies to EVERY PPA out there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a problem with apt-get, the location you are trying to download from does not exist. If you look at https://launchpad.net/~openshot.developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa there is no trusty (14.04) ppa.

Comment: Well, why don't you help me since that is in my sources.list? I never changed anything. That's default.

Comment: No its not default, adding PPAs changes your sources list. You have added PPAs that do not have any packages for the version of Ubuntu you have installed.

Comment: You're wrong. I added the OBS PPA and it said that it was for 14.04 trusty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: Nope. Please read my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this and I feel really dumb for not knowing this.

Okay, the problem was that at some point, I added the 1386 architecture instead of i386. So when I tried to update with apt-get, it couldn't download the 32-bit packages. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As NGRhodes points out, there simply isn't a 14.04 version of this PPA. You say you get this for *every PPA*... If that's really the case, you're either picking a load of duff PPAs without checking they have a 14.04 version, there's something else going on.

Anyway, for this one, you have a couple of options:

- You can continue as you are (in the hope that they add one eventually) and nothing will be hurt. The warning is just a warning, the rest of the package lists *are* being updated still.
- You can remove the PPA:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
  ```

  The next `sudo apt update` should be warning free.